# Receives request return JSON only when status is 200

Tags: json, delphi, indy

I am sending a bank statement (JSON) file to an API. The problem is, I can only get the response JSON when my request status is 200. When not, an exception is thrown but the API response JSON is not enough. To know what is wrong I created the same structure in Postman, so I know what is missing / wrong in my JSON.
I am using Delphi 2007 and my version of Indy is 10.1.5.

For example

When you make a particular submission, you throw this exception:
**raised exception class EIdHTTPProtocolException with Message 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'**

When I send the same JSON through Postman:

```
{
    "codigo": "validation_error",
    "mensagem": "Erro na validação de campos",
    "campos": [
        {
            "campo": "digito_verificador_nosso_numero",
            "mensagem": "Digito Verificador do Nosso Número Inválido!(DAC10)",
            "valor": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why is the JSON that is received when I make the request in Postman not received when I make it through indy?
It simply throws the exception and terminates.

I am making the requests this way:

```
  JsonRet := TStringStream.Create('');
  vEnviar := TStringStream.Create(body);
  try
    http := dtmGlobal.http1;
    http.Request.Clear;
    http.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    http.Request.Charset := 'UTF-8';
    http.Request.Accept := ACCEPT;
    http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('access_token', ACredencial.Token);
    http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('itau-chave', ACredencial.Chave);
    http.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('identificador', SoNumeros(CnpjCedente));

    try
      http.Post(URLBOLETO, vEnviar, jsonRet);
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      begin
        ErrMsg(9995);
      end;
    end;

  finally
    result := JsonRet.DataString;
    result := http.ResponseText;
  end;
end
```

Comment: Newer versions of Indy have an option `hoWantProtocolErrorContent` which when enabled, and a protocol error occurs (such as receiving error response code), you'll still receive the content. I can't find the original question to link though, I do recall having a similar problem and Remy (with Indy) ended up adding this option for this scenario.

Comment: 10.1.5 is an extremely old version of Indy. The current version is 10.6.2.5519. You should seriously consider upgrading. Modern `TIdHTTP` has features not present in 10.1.5 to handle this exactly type of situation.